# How do I get the bounds of my Slider to correspond to the current length of a string entered in another control?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction, slider

I have a text entry control in a `Manipulate` that I index into the value of using the value of a `Slider` control. This works as expected, except that when I delete enough characters the current value of my `Slider` goes out of the bounds of the control.

For example if using

```
Manipulate[{txt, char} // TableForm,
 {{txt, "", "T"}, InputField[Dynamic[txt], String, ContinuousAction -> True] &},
 {{char, If[False, StringLength[txt], 1], "C"}, 
  Slider[Dynamic[char], {1, StringLength[txt], 1}, 
  Enabled -> StringLength[txt] > 1, Appearance -> "Tiny"] &}]
```

I have

[image]

and delete 2 characters of text, I get

[image]

when what I want is

[image]

That is, I would like, as I delete characters, for the bounds of my `Slider` to update to correspond to the current length of the string that is the value of the text entry control.

---

FWIW, in part of my implementation, text entry does not use `InputField` but instead uses a `Button` to delete the last character only. So the desirable solution should work for either text entered using `InputField` (and thus potentially deleted from any point) and text that can only be deleted from the end using a `Button`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{txt}, {idx}}],
 Grid[{
   {"T", InputField[Dynamic[txt, {txt = #; idx = StringLength[txt]} &], 
   String, ContinuousAction -> True]},
   {"index", Manipulator[Dynamic[idx, {idx = #} &], 
   {0, Dynamic@StringLength[txt], 1}], Dynamic[idx]}
   }],
 {{txt, ""}, None},
 {{idx, 0}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Not quite. It looks like all I need to do is replace `Dynamic[txt]` with `Dynamic[txt, {txt = #; char = Min[char, StringLength[txt]]} &]`. Am I missing something by doing that?

Comment: BTW: How are you capturing the `Manipulate` animations; that's very useful?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I use LICEcap to record it from the screen as animated gif file. I hope someone can understand better the solution you need and provide better implementation. good luck.

Comment: Sorry: It's a great solution. I just was wondering if it needed to be so different from the example I gave.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius the solution uses the second argument of dynamic. I do not know how else to solve it, but there might be a way to do it without using the second argument of dynamics. I do not know.